# Is there any Angular 4 Performance tool like react-perf for React Application?

Tags: angular, angular4-router

Is there any Angular 4 Performance tool to test the angular component rendering performance
like react-perf for React Application?

Answer (score 1):

As @Pablo mentioned, there is no such tool. Chrome dev tools is your best friend here.

The following article might help as well.

https://blog.oasisdigital.com/2017/angular-runtime-performance-guide/

Comment: Thanks @Sonu Kapoor

Answer (score -1):

Chrome dev tools.

Anyway react says: "As of React 16, react-addons-perf is not supported. Please use your browser’s profiling tools to get insight into which components re-render."

Comment: My question was for Angular !!